# How can I run nosetests in the root of a repository?

Tags: python, repository, root, nose

I am using python 3.8 in spyder and installed nose using 'pip install nose' but am unsure what it mans to run 'nosetests' in the root of the repository as given by the readme.md. I tried copying the path from environment variables with cd before and nose tests after. Every time I attempt to run nose tests it results in NameError: name 'nosetests' is not defined. I think my issue is finding the root of my repository but I don't know how to do that. Additionally I tried nosetests -h.

I am using python 3.8 in spyder and installed nose using 'pip install nose' but am unsure what it mans to run 'nosetests' in the root of the repository as given by the readme.md. I tried copying the path from environment variables with cd before and nose tests after. Every time I attempt to run nose tests it results in NameError: name 'nosetests' is not defined. I think my issue is finding the root of my repository but I don't know how to do that. Additionally I tried nosetests -h.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.